# Trying to do a calculation with a text field and a number in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

The problem I'm having is that when an option in a drop-down box is selected, I need the selected option to be entered into a calculation in another field. However, the selected option is a number but due to the selected option from the drop-down box being formatted as "text", it is not allowing me to make the calculation I need in the following field as it needs to be a number format.

Is there a way I can change the selected option from the drop-down into a number in order to enter it into my calculation?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Cognito Forms leverages .Net syntax for it's expression parsing. You would need to use the Int32.Parse or Decimal.Parse methods to convert the text value of the choice field to a number.

For example: If you had a form with 2 fields, one is a Currency field called Unit Price and then a choice field, called Quantity with options 1, 2, 3. You could then add a calculation field to the form with a calculation expression of =Decimal.Parse(Quantity) * UnitPrice